# Update map using findAll and each in groovy

Tags: groovy

I would like to update values in map in Groovy filling certain criteria. Here is my code:

```
def m = [:]
m['a'] = 1
m['b'] = 2
m['d'] = 3
m.findAll { it.value > 1}.each { 
it.value = 4
}
println m
```

But the result is following:

```
[a:1, b:2, d:3]
```

Is there any way to do it using both findAll and each? Or I must use

```
m.each {if (it.value>1) it.value=4}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The root cause is `findAll` returns a **new Map instance**.

So you could try:

```
newMap = m.findAll { it.value > 1}.each { 
    it.value = 4
}
println m      //No change
println newMap //This is what you need!
```

output is

```
[a:1, b:2, d:3] 
[b:4, d:4]
```

Comment: or `[ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 ].collectEntries { ( it.value > 1 ) ? [ "${it.key}" : 4 ] : it }` ---> `[a:1, b:4, c:4]`. or filter via `[ 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 ].findAll{ it.value > 1 }.collectEntries { ["${it.key}" : 4 ] }` ---> `[b:4, c:4]`

Answer (score 5):

In each case, the values you are iterating with the `each` are map entries with a pointer to key and value.  When you set `it.value` you are not replacing what is in the map.  You are only updating the pointer in the map entry.   To actually set the value, you will need to do the following:

```
m.findAll { it.value > 1 }.each { m[it.key] = 4 }
```

Comment: Yep, that is correct too, however there is bigger complexity: O(n^2)

Comment: Actually in this case it is just O(2n).  The `findAll` will take n steps and at worst, the `each` will then take n steps as well.